# Automatic connect to VPN in Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn

I have my VPN set up properly in Windows Server 2003. But there are some issue in it.

I have always been scheduled a restart at midnight, when the restart finish, the VPN does not automaticaly reconnect again. I've look in the options but no where to be found. Can someone point out where should I setup so that my VPN will automatically reconnect at windows startup?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that Server 2003 is the client machine, not the VPN host?

If this is the case, I strongly suggest using the RRAS (Routing and Remote Access) component of the operating system, and configuring the VPN as an interface in there.

Why? Because those VPNs can be set as Persistant, in that they will come up as soon as the machine boots, and stay up nomatter who is logged on or what is going on. If the internet drops out (or the machine is restarted), and then comes back it will automatically re-connect when it can, and is invisible to the end user.

You can also set up a static route that gets created whenever the VPN connection comes online, so that any remote networks will be immediately visible as well.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to server 2003, but in 2012 and probably 2008, you can just use the "Task Scheduler" feature to run "c:\windows\system32\rasdial.exe", set the arguments to the name of the VPN connection in quotes, triggered to run on startup, and specify the option "Run whether user is logged on or not". You don't have to be on a domain (mine isn't), but make sure the task is set to "Run with highest privileges", and also make sure your credentials are saved in the VPN connection, because you definitely don't want to put them in plain text in the argument list for the task.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way, and a hard way

Easy way, auto-login the account after startup, with the shortcut to the vpn connection in the startup folder, with password remembered.

This will start it on auto-login, but if the connection goes down, unless you have auto-redial enabled, it will stay down.

Hard way, don't use windows VPN client, use something like OpenVPN which allows itself to run as a service therefore starting up when the machine starts up.

Comment: Auto-login on a server is a *bad* idea

Comment: Not sure if this applies to server 2003, but in 2012 and probably 2008, you can just use the "Task Scheduler" feature to run "c:\windows\system32\rasdial.exe", set the arguments to the name of the VPN connection in quotes, triggered to run on startup, and specify the option "Run whether user is logged on or not".  You don't have to be on a domain, but make sure the task is set to "Run with highest privileges", and also make sure your credentials are saved in the VPN connection, because you definitely don't want to put them in plain text in the argument list for the task.